# Evaluating covariant derivative terms of a scalar function (xAct, xTras)

Tags: xact

I am trying to use xAct package to calculate certain mixing terms of $\nabla_{\chi} b$ of a scalar function $b[ \tau, r, \theta, \phi]$ for a modified metric. Here is my Code:

```
<< xAct`xTras`
ddim = 4;
coords = {\[Tau][], r[], \[Theta][], \[Phi][]};

DefManifold[M4, 
  ddim, {\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Gamma], \[Sigma], \[Mu], \[Nu]}];
DefMetric[-1, g[-\[Alpha], -\[Beta]], CD, PrintAs -> "g"];
DefScalarFunction[{a, \[Eta], b}];
DefChart[ch, M4, {0, 1, 2, 3}, coords, ChartColor -> Red];
DefConstantSymbol[K]

FRWr = DiagonalMatrix[{
   -\[Eta][\[Tau][]]^2,
   b[\[Tau][], r[], \[Theta][], \[Phi][]]^2/(1 - K r[]^2),
   b[\[Tau][], r[], \[Theta][], \[Phi][]]^2 r[]^2,
   b[\[Tau][], r[], \[Theta][], \[Phi][]]^2 r[]^2 Sin[\[Theta][]]^2
   }
  ]

MatrixForm@MetricInBasis[g, -ch, FRWr]
MetricCompute[g, ch, Einstein, Verbose -> True]

CD[-\[Alpha]]@CD[\[Alpha]]@b

CD[-\[Alpha]]@CD[\[Alpha]]@b[\[Tau][], r[], \[Theta][], \[Phi][]]

CD[-\[Alpha]]@b CD[\[Alpha]]@b

CD[-\[Alpha]]@b CD[\[Alpha]]@b g[-\[Mu], -\[Nu]]

(CD[-\[Alpha]]@b CD[\[Alpha]]@b) g[-\[Mu], -\[Nu]] g[\[Gamma], \[Sigma]]
```

The output of the last 5 lines is here:

[image]

How can I evaluate these abstract outputs? I have tried using `//ToBasis[ch]// ToValues` but didn't help either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: What is variable "ch"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend to do the following. Keep this part of your code:

```
<< xAct`xTras`

ddim = 4;
coords = {\[Tau][], r[], \[Theta][], \[Phi][]};

DefManifold[M4, ddim, {\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Gamma], \[Sigma], \[Mu], \[Nu]}];
DefScalarFunction[{a, \[Eta], b}];
DefChart[ch, M4, {0, 1, 2, 3}, coords, ChartColor -> Red];
DefConstantSymbol[K]

FRWr = DiagonalMatrix[{
    -\[Eta][\[Tau][]]^2, 
    b[\[Tau][], r[], \[Theta][], \[Phi][]]^2/(1 - K r[]^2), 
    b[\[Tau][], r[], \[Theta][], \[Phi][]]^2 r[]^2, 
    b[\[Tau][], r[], \[Theta][], \[Phi][]]^2 r[]^2 Sin[\[Theta][]]^2
}]
```

You don't need to use a symbolic metric g. We can just work with this explicit metric:

```
g = CTensor[FRWr, {-ch, -ch}]
```

Compute everything up to the Einstein tensor and set this metric as the one to be used to raise/lower indices automatically:

```
MetricCompute[g, ch, "Einstein", Verbose -> True]
SetCMetric[g, ch, SignatureOfMetric -> {3, 1, 0}]
```

Get the associated Levi-Civita connection:

```
CD = CovDOfMetric[g];
```

Now you can compute the Laplacian of a scalar:

```
bsc = b[\[Tau][], r[], \[Theta][], \[Phi][]]

CD[-\[Alpha]]@CD[\[Alpha]]@bsc
```

or the square of a gradient:

```
CD[-\[Alpha]]@bsc CD[\[Alpha]]@bsc
```

This case requires some further simplification:

```
BasisExpand[%, ch] // Simplify
```

Note that you cannot compute derivatives of b, because b is a function. You first need to specify the arguments of that scalar function (that's the scalar bsc).

Comment: Great, thank you very much Jose. Defining explicit metric in your way via CTensor solved my issues.